# Javascript: Replace 'x' only if it is the first word of a text, not anywhere else

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

I'm working on a simple JS code to replace some words with others in a text using an array.

```
<textarea id="text1">
e mi e
ke fo
e di
</textarea>
<button  type="button" onclick="myFunction()">try</button>
<pre id="demo"></pre>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var str = document.getElementById("text1").value; 
    var mapObj = {
        "k":"g",
        " e": "B",
        "e":"ar"
    };

    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, function(matched){
    return mapObj[matched];
    });
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```

The result is:

```
ar mi B
gar fo
ar di
```

But I desire to have this:

```
B mi B
gar fo
B di
```

If `"e"`s are to be changed before `" e"`s (separated `e` with a space before it), then `" e"`s will not be `" e"` but "ar", so in the array, I've put `" e"` above `"e"` and it works well.
 
However the problem is that the text may contain a separated `"e"` as the first word of the whole text or as the first word of a line with no space before it. When it's the case how can I replace this separated `"e"`with `"B"` and prevent it from being replaced with `"ar"`.

Comment: little bit confused (maybe its just me), could you please add an example that shows the issue? The example you gave is giving the desired output I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the `.replace` function is only taking a single variable input. This limits you from using more specific RegExp in your replace, as the matched element will not match the regex.

`.replace`'s function option provides access to matched groups as the [`1+n`th variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). As a result we can leverage this to lookup our replacement strings in an array.

By utilising RegExp groups we can capture the values we're looking for and replace them as needed.

**JS**

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var regexs = ['(k)','(^e|\\se)', '(e)'];
    var replacers = ['g', 'B', 'ar'];
    var re = new RegExp(regexs.join("|"),"gi");
    // you would need to add variables to the function for each matching group you add (currently there are 3 so we have 3 groups)
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, function(raw, group0, group1, group2){
        if(typeof group0 !== "undefined"){
            return replacers[0]; // replaces with 'g'
        }else if(typeof group1 !== "undefined"){
            // skip over the first character (white space) and concatenate the replacement
            return raw[0] + replacers[1]; // replaces with 'B'
        }else if(typeof group2 !== "undefined"){
            return replacers[2]; // replaces with 'ar'
        }
        return raw;
    });
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
};
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

**CSS**

```
#demo{
    white-space:pre;
}
```

**NOTE**: because you're outputting to an elements `.innerHTML` without the above CSS new lines are not displayed.

[**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/51bq8a8L/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try The below code.

```
function myFunction() {
   var str = document.getElementById("text1").value; 
    str = str.toLowerCase().split('k').join('g').split(' e').join(' B').split('\\n').join(' B').split('e').join('ar');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Its a different approach but I got the expected output.

Comment: I have save this code snippet in JS fiddle. [https://jsfiddle.net/9k2khb0x/](https://jsfiddle.net/9k2khb0x/)

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myfunction = function(){

  var f = document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML;
  var c = f.replace(/e/ig,'ar').replace(/\bar/ig,'B').replace(/k/ig,'g');
  document.getElementById('text1').innerHTML = c;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
<textarea id="source" cols="5" rows="5">
e mi e
ke fo
e di
</textarea>

<button  type="button" onclick="convert()">Convert</button>

<textarea id="destination" cols="5" rows="5">
</textarea>

<script>
function replaceWord(searchFor, replaceWith, paragraph) {
    if (paragraph) {
        var lines = paragraph.split('\n');
        for (lineNo = 0; lineNo < lines.length; lineNo++) {
            var words = lines[lineNo].split(' ');
            for (wordNo = 0; wordNo < words.length; wordNo++) {
                if (words[wordNo] === searchFor) {
                    words[wordNo] = replaceWith;
                }
            }
            lines[lineNo] = words.join(' ');
        }

        paragraph = lines.join('\n');
    }

    return paragraph;
}

function replaceWords(wordMap, paragraph) {
    for(var searchFor in wordMap)
    {
        if(wordMap.hasOwnProperty(searchFor))
        {
            paragraph = replaceWord(searchFor, wordMap[searchFor], paragraph);
        }
    }
    return paragraph;
}

function convert() {

    var mapObj = {
        "ke":"gar",
        "e": "B"
    };

    var source = document.getElementById("source");
    var destination = document.getElementById("destination");

    destination.value = replaceWords(mapObj, source.value);
}
</script>
```

Here is the jsFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/1egs7zgc/

For what it's worth, your mapObj isn't really an array it's an object.